Intuition Behind Forming a Quotient of a Free Abelian Group by a Single Relation
I'm studying free abelian groups and came across the construction of a quotient group defined by introducing a single relation. Specifically, if $G=H/\langle r\rangle$, where $H$ is a free abelian group and $\langle r\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by a relation $r$, I'm trying to build an intuitive understanding of what this quotient represents.
Could someone provide some intuition or an example that illustrates how introducing a relation affects the structure of the free abelian group?

Start with $\mathbb{Z}$, the free abelian group with one generator...

The idea is that you’re setting $r$ to be the identity and finding the consequences of that change.

Take the free (non-abelian) group on two generators $x$ and $y$, and impose the relation $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$. What can you say about your new group?

Please avoid answering questions in the comment section. This is not how comments are supposed to be used: they should only clarify the problem, and answers should be posted as answers. See here for more information.

Roughly speaking, this is the algebraic method of "declaring $r$ as a zero element in $H$".
Example 1: Working in dimension $1$ (i.e. $H=\mathbb{Z}$). Then $r\in \mathbb{Z}$ is a natural number. In this case $\left<r\right> = r\cdot \mathbb{Z}$ is the group of all integer multiples of $r$. The quotient $H/\left<r\right> = \mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ is the group of addition modulo $r$.
Namely, every elemenet in $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ takes the form $x+r\mathbb{Z}$ for some $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. Here $x+r\mathbb{Z}$ is a set (sometimes called a coset) consisting of all $x+nr$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Namely,
$$x+r\mathbb{Z} = \{x+ n\cdot r : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
Note that $x+r\mathbb{Z}$ are not necessarily distinct, for instance $r+r\mathbb{Z} = 0+r\mathbb{Z}$ (exercise - this is what I mean by "declaring $r$ as the zero element").
The key point here is that we can add these sets together, using the following definition $$(x+r\mathbb{Z}) + (y+r\mathbb{Z}) = (x+y)+r\mathbb{Z}$$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$.
Example 2: In higher dimensions the situation is more interesting. For instance, the quotient can be used to decrease the dimension. For example, if $H=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $r=(0,1)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, then $H/\left<r\right>$ is a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, observe that $\left<r\right> = \{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}$. Then, we have an isomorphism
$$\varphi: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ defined by
$$\varphi((x,y) + \{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}) = x$$
This $\varphi$ is well defined, because it does not depend on the choice of the coset. Namely, if $(x,y)+\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z} = (x',y')+\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}$ then $x=x'$ and so $\varphi((x,y)+\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}) = \varphi((\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}))$. I will leave it as an exercise for you to prove that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.
Example 3: One needs to be careful though, sometimes the quotient does not change the group at all up to isomorphism. For example if $H = \bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. the infinite direct summand of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$) and $r = (1,0,0,0,...)$, then $H/\left<r\right>$ is isomorphic to $H$ with respect to the isomorphism $\varphi((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} + \left<r\right>) = y$ where $y=(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $y_n = x_{n+1}$.
